# Error in regexp Go lang

Tags: regex, go, functional-programming

I'm trying to use this regular expressions in Go lang:

```
~((?<=^[^\s])|(?<=\s[^\s]))\s(?=[^\s](\s|$))~

{(c|d|e|i|l|n|o|p|r|t|z)\1+}

{( |a|b|d|[f-h]|i|[j-k]|m|q|s|[u-y])\1+}

{(c|d|e|i|l|n|o|p|r|t|z)\1+}

{( |a|b|[f-h]|i|[j-k]|m|q|s|[u-y])\1+}

{(si|sa|za|ja|to)\1+}
```

and in everyone of those i get this error:

> panic: regexp: Compile(`~((?<=^[^\s])|(?<=\s[^\s]))\s(?=[^\s](\s|$))~`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?<`

Maybe there is a trick know for someone? :/ or is it impossible to use them?

Comment: Doesn't allow lookbehinds: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax. It also doesn't support lookaheads

Comment: Lookarounds are not supported in the stdlib regular expression parser: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/

Comment: know if it's possible to find alone characters with regexp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no lookbehinds supported, use a workaround like this:

`((^|\s)\S)(\s)(?=\S(\s|$))`

where:

Capture group 1 contains what's to be written back in place of the
lookbehind.

Capture group 3 is the actual whitespace in question.
It's in a capture group just to separate it from the entire match.

Summary: Group 1 + Group 3 = entire match.

Expanded:

```
 #  (                             # (1 start)
 #       (?<= ^ [^\s] )
 #    |  (?<= \s [^\s] )
 #  )                             # (1 end)

 (                             # (1 start)
      ( ^ | \s )                    # (2)
      \S 
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( \s )                        # (3)
 (?=
      \S 
      ( \s | $ )                    # (4)
 )
```

Comment: positive lookahead are not supported supported too :'(

Comment: Oh, you're right. Then the only option is you have to capture before and after `((^|\s)\S)(\s)(\S(\s|$))`. But, this sets the next match position past the last `\s` which could be used for that match if `\s` from the last match were available. If you are replacing the middle `\s` with a non-space, you could restart the match from the beginning each time. Another alternative is to set the match position each time if that's possible. The final alternative is to scrap the crappy language and get a real lang that doesn't use RE2.

Comment: At the end i opted for creating a function to join stand alone characters:

Comment: func joinStandAloneChars(str string) string{
    arrayStr:= strings.Split(str," ")
    newStr := ""
    for _,element := range arrayStr{
        if element != " " && element != ""{ 
            if len(element) == 1 {
                newStr += element;
            }else{
                if len(newStr)>1 && string(newStr[len(newStr)-1:]) == " "   {
                    newStr += element +" ";
                }else{
                    newStr +=" "+ element +" ";
                }
                
            }
        } 
    }
    return newStr
}

Comment: regexp of go gave me a headeache :(